# What is 'code repeat' exactly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read from the book(Beginning Python From Novice to Profession) that "it is usually thought as a bad thing to repeat code"(I'm not native speaker, so I'm not sure how it is wrote Initially), and says:

```
#===11-7===
file = open(PATH)
while True:
    char = file.read(1)
    if not char: 
        break
    print('Processing:', char)
file.close()
```

Is better than:

```
#===11-6===
file = open(PATH)
char = file.read(1)
    while char:
        print('Processing:', char)
        char = file.read(1)
file.close()
```

because 11-7 avoids the code repeating. So I'm here to ask: what is code repeating? And is it so bad?

Merely judged form 11-6 I din't see some sort of the... disadvantages, and to be honest, if I haven't watch the book, I would perfer to code like 11-6. Thanks~

Comment: Basically, there's no reason to write the *same line* of code multiple times if you don't have to.

Comment: You can subtly introduce bugs should you decide to read *2* bytes instead of one, and only make that change in one of the two `.read()` calls. Happens all the time in practice.

Comment: This answer summarisies IMO the key point: "DRY should be used to avoid the situation where two pieces of code are conceptually doing some of the same work, so whenever you change the code in one place you have to change the code in the other place. If the same logic is in two separate places, then you have to always remember to change the logic in both places, which can be quite error prone. " http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790368/6260170

Comment: "What is 'code repeat' exactly [duplicate]" <- I'm sorry but this is hysterical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example does does the read operation in two places. So--

Imagine that you wrote this code, and at some point in the future, you change how you're reading the data; perhaps now you want to read it over the network instead of from a file, or you want to use a different function to read from the file. In the first example you only have to change "file.read(1)" in one place, whereas in the second you have to do it in two, and you might miss one of them, or make a mistake, etc.

Similarly, you might discover a bug in the code, and accidentally only fix it in one of the two places.

Now this is obviously a simplified example, where it doesn't matter too much, but in real-world programs mistakes like this are very easy to make: imagine that it's not a single line but 50 lines of duplicated code, and someone fixes a bug in one copy but not in the other. You now have a problem that is potentially very difficult to debug!